# How to check for interaction of all pairs of variables, in linear regression in R?

Tags: r, regression

I am fitting a linear model in R with many variables:

`lm(Y~X1+X2+...+X100)`

I want to check also for all pairwise interactions. Writing `X1*X2*...*X100` is not good since it checks the full model (more than pairwise). Writing all pairs explicitly is annoying (100 over 2). Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: To reliably estimate a coefficient takes a deal more than a couple of points per coefficient. You're talking about estimating 5050 parameters (plus an intercept and $\sigma$). Do you have enough data for all that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The help for `formula` tells you how to do this. You should really read that. It's:

```
y ~ (x1 + x2 + ...)^2
```